# How to remove duplicate labels in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

On My Flask Server- On one side I am showing a webcam in which my YOLO model is running. On another side I am Showing a Table in which the detected objects are shown along with their timestamps. My concern is that it prints the labels- Object, Probability and Timestamps again and again. After every detected Object it prints the labels

here is the code.

```
x = []
for i in l:
    x = i.split(" ")
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Object': [x[0]], 'Probability': [x[1]],
                       'Timestamp': [datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M%p")]})
    df.sort_values(by='Timestamp', ascending=False, kind='quicksort', inplace=True)
    # df.sort_values(by='Timestamp', ascending=False, kind='quicksort')
    df.to_csv('objects.csv', mode='a', index=False, encoding="utf8")
```

I am taking things in a for loop because the webcam is continuously running.

I expect my code should show something like:

```
Object | Probability | Timestamp
person | 0.98        | Thursday, 13. June 2019 03:25PM
backpack| 0.75       | Thursday, 13. June 2019 03:25PM
Bottle | 0.83        | Thursday, 13. June 2019 03:26PM
```

What it is looking now:

```
Object | Probability | Timestamp
person | 0.98        | Thursday, 13. June 2019 03:25PM
Object | Probability | Timestamp
backpack| 0.75       | Thursday, 13. June 2019 03:25PM
Object | Probability | Timestamp
Bottle | 0.83        | Thursday, 13. June 2019 03:26PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the headers from the `to_csv`:

```
    df.to_csv('objects.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False, encoding="utf8")
```

and write them once, before the loop:

```
with open('objects.csv', 'wb') as fd:
    fd.write(b'Object,Probability,Timestamp\r\n')
for i in l:
    ...
```